# What is the best way to fit carpet tiles on the old carpet in my campervan where there seems to be some mould?

Tags: campervan

I have an old camper van and I’d like to renew the carpets without spending too much. The off-cuts are quite expensive but I got carpet tiles for under 20 bucks and I love their color.

I’m planning to fit them over the old one using carpet tape so that I have some more insulation, however, after removing the furniture and lifting the old carpet, I noticed there’s a good bit of mold from the leaks.

I’m planning to vacuum clean the wood and the old carpet, but what other precautions do I need to have?

What about the folds on the edges? I mean the ones on the door step and the small step in the middle of the van?

Anything else I should know?

[image: van living area]

[image: the door step]

[image: under the carpet by the window where there’s a leak]

[image: a closer look under the carpet]

Comment: Are you saying the black speckles is mould?

Comment: It seems that it’s a mix of mould and carpet fluff.